# ASP.net MVC - Multiple Forms on View, each calling a different action, but need to show the same view again

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, controller, postback

I have 3 forms on my View.  Each of these all post back to a different action.  When the action is complete, I call my original Action that led the user to the page originally, but MVC is looking for a view of the postback Action.  How can I get MVC to post to an action of a different name of the current view, while still having it reload the same page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return this when you are done with your post pack Action:

```
return RedirectToAction("OriginalAction");
```

Comment: Liked the way this one worked.  I had to pass in the parameter it needed as well, so just put RedirectToAction("OriginalAction", new {param = "blah"});

Answer (score 2):

How I would solve the problem:

In your view, for each form:

```
<% using(Html.BeginForm<ControllerController>(c => c.Action1(param))
{
    // Form Stuff
} %>
```

In your action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Action1(type param)
{
    // Do your work;
    return this.RedirectToAction(c => c.OrigionalAction(param));
}
```

The strongly typed Html.BeginForm is from MVCFutures (Microsoft.Web.Mvc)
The strongly typed RedirectToAction is from MvcContrib.

Comment: totally off topic, but thanx, used mvc a while ago, and in the new project i couldn't figure out how i managed the strongly typed forms and actions